# UINavigationBar BarButtonItems don't respond to taps when view has been shifted up for keyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationbar, uikeyboard

I shift a modal view up when the keyboard is displayed to prevent some parts of the interface being hidden by the keyboard.

When the view has been shifted, the toolbar cancel / save buttons don't respond to taps. Taps inside the modal are detected and respond fine.

[image]

I've set it up so that the keyboard should dismiss when tapping outside the textfield, but this doesn't work when tapping on the navigation bar either.

**How can I respond appropriately to taps on barbuttonitems when the view has been offset?**

Here's how I am shifting the modal up when the keyboard is displayed:

```
- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    int movementDistance;
    float movementDuration;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        if(
           UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)
          )
        { 
            //code for landscape shift - not relevant because you can't see the toolbar
       else{
            NSLog(@"Portrait for animation");
            movementDistance = IPAD_PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT; 
            movementDuration = KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION; 

            if(up){
                keyboardAppearedInLandscape = false;   
            }else{
                //the keyboard is going down
                NSLog(@"Keyboard going down");
                //is the iPad in the same orientation now that it was when it came up?
                if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
                {
                    if (!keyboardAppearedInLandscape) {
                        //don't do anything - the keyboard is being dismissed in the same way it was called. It's much the same in any case.
                    }else{
                        movementDistance = IPAD_LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } 
    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
//end text field movy-ness
```

And here is how I am detecting taps outside the textfield to dismiss the keyboard:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {      
        //keyboard goes away if you tap somewhere else on screen
        NSLog(@"resignFirstResponder");
        [self.view endEditing:YES];

    }

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}
```

Comment: is your touches handler interfering?  i.e. if you comment out your touches[Began] methods, do the toolbar buttons work?

Comment: No they don't - I can completely remove that code with no affect (except for the keyboard dismissing).

Comment: where is the toolbar in relation to the stuff you're moving?  Is it being moved too?  Are you possibly moving your view on top of the toolbar?

Comment: The Navigation Bar is part of the view (i.e. 'inside' the view). Nothing visible is on top of the toolbar, and I don't have any transparent elements. Yes the navbar moves up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You won't receive touch events outside the original rectangle bounds, because...**

- `SuperView` thinks that the view hasn't changed location
- View is moving up within itself instead of from outside
- Visual elements on the screen are changing but aren't being recognized

### Instead, to move the subview properly:

1. `SuperView` should be responding to the `UIKeyboard`

   - Utilize `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` && `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`
2. Set `ClipsToBounds to YES`

   - Now you won't see stuff that's outside of the view's bounds.
   - Makes debugging more effective

---

Check out:

- [Add done button to a UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131660/add-a-done-button-in-a-uinavigationbar) @StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are moving the view up within itself, rather than from outside.  So, the visual elements on the screen are changing, but according to your SuperView, the view is in the same place, so you will only get touch events inside the original rectangle (this rectangle is called the "bounds").

Instead, your SuperView should be responding to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` to move the subview to the proper place.

You can debug this kind of stuff more easily if you set `ClipsToBounds` to `YES`.  This will make it so you can't see stuff that is outside of the view's "bounds" (the area that can receive touch events.)